# jadeテンプレートでiterationから抜け出す方法を教えてください

Tags: html, node.js, templates

jadeテンプレートで、breakやreturnのように、iteration（繰り返し）から抜け出す方法を教えてください。
http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

Answer (score 1):

```
break
```

だとダメでしたが、

```
- break
```

ならいけました。

Comment: この回答で問題解決した場合には、自身の回答を accept しましょう。、